# S3 throwing 400 Bad Request when using axios

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, axios

I am trying to do a `HEAD` Request to my Amazon S3 from my `React App` using `axios` and I keep getting the following error

```
Unhandled promise rejection Error: "Request failed with status code 400"
```

My Bucket Policy is like this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And my `CORS` configuration is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

The error does not occor when i do a `Postman` request or a `curl -I` request but occors when I use `axios`

My code is very simple and looks like this

```
const { data: headerData } = await axios.head(url);
console.log("headerData", headerData);
```

Is there anything wrong with this?

Thanks

S3 Pics,

[image: Network One]
[image: Network Two]

Comment: I'd expect there to be a more detailed error message contained in the 400 response. Could you capture and print that out.

Comment: `Authorization: Bearer` is not valid for S3. Where is that request header coming from?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That is due to the Authorization I've set in axios for the portal login. Do you think that also can cause problem.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, Okay so inside the portal I used `delete axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"];
` and also used `<ExposeHeader>` to expose it. Making the edits. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works fine for me, outside of a browser, against a publicly readable object:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const s3url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/cat.jpg';

const headObject = async (url) => {
  const { headers } = await axios.head(url);
  console.log('headers', headers);
};

headObject(s3url);
```

So, presumably the issue you have is related to CORS. Could you add the following to the bucket's CORSRule configuration and retry:

```
<ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
```

If you have custom metadata, then also add (replacing `custom-header` with your metadata name):

```
<ExposeHeader>x-amz-meta-custom-header</ExposeHeader>
```

Comment: Hey, I have uploaded the pics. But for my S3 Bucket it's still coming 400.

Comment: Is there anything in the response body?

Comment: Nope, It's empty.

Comment: `<ExposeHeader>` does the job. Thanks.